# How get config file values in other config file - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, config

I have two config files, "**config/oauth-5-laravel.php**" and "**config/wtv.php**", i need to get the values of wtv.php file into another file called oauth-5-laravel.php like this:

"oauth-5-laravel.php":

```
'consumers' => [

    'Facebook' => [
        'client_id'     => config('wtv.social.facebook.client_id'),
        'client_secret' => config('wtv.social.facebook.client_secret'),
        'scope'         => ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_location', 'user_hometown', 'user_birthday', 'user_about_me'],
    ],

    'Google' => [
        'client_id'     => config('wtv.social.google.client_id'),
        'client_secret' => config('wtv.social.google.client_secret'),
        'scope'         => ['profile', 'email'],
    ],

    'Twitter' => [
        'client_id'     => config('wtv.social.twitter.client_id'),
        'client_secret' => config('wtv.social.twitter.client_secret'),
    ],

]
```

"wtv.php":

```
'social' => [

    'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => '1696561373912147',
        'client_secret' => '496dbca22495c95ddb699c2a1f0397cf',
    ],

    'google' => [
        'client_id' => '647043320420-tted6rbtl78iodemmt2o2nlglbu7gvsg.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'client_secret' => 'PLpQ5lv5lT_wV9ElXzAKfrOD',
    ],

    'twitter' => [
        'client_id' => 'dQYHIZDQZGDSLZy4ZDto9lxBh',
        'client_secret' => 'je1aFIFbkH4UpqPDZgEqoCIAg1Ul6lO67JoycDAzS2EzCZqszk',
    ],

],
```

and not work.

Comment: you just posted your secret data :)

Comment: They are test data ;)

Comment: @Radavel I'd still suggest resetting tokens. There's potential to screw with your test applications here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bad news:** you can't use `config()` in config files as one config file can't be sure that other config file was loaded.

**Good news:** there's the right way to perform your task.

First of all, in `wtv.php` there's array key which is called `client_secret`. You see, **secret**. All secret data should not be in config files and VCS repository (e.g. Git repository).

Instead, `.env` file which is not in repo should be used.

Your case will look like this:

**.env**

```
facebook_client_id=1696561373912147
facebook_client_secret=496dbca22495c95ddb699c2a1f0397cf
...
```

**oauth-5-laravel.php**

'consumers' => [

```
'Facebook' => [
    'client_id'     => env('facebook_client_id'),
    'client_secret' => env('facebook_client_secret'),
...
```

**wtv.php**

'social' => [

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('facebook_client_id'),
    'client_secret' => env('facebook_client_secret'),
...
```

You will also be able to use different data for testing (dev) and live (production) servers by changing variables in `.env` file.

`.env` file is not php file, but regular text file which will be parsed by [PHP dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv).

Read more about environment configuration: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#environment-configuration

Comment: No way to rename the file .env?

Comment: .env file isn't php file. I suggest you to read this short and useful article: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-laravel-environment-variables

Comment: you're welcome :) don't forget very important rule - "You should never store sensitive credentials in your code".

Comment: never share your sensitive credentials in public. you can replace it with dummy text or number while asking question..